# How to Redirect 301 /subfolder/page-url https://mydomain/subfolder/new-page-url

Tags: .htaccess

I tried to redirect using this method via htaccess but there is no redirection is occured.
Please correct me if there is any mistake.

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder/page-url https://mydomain/subfolder/new-page-url
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to redirect such a single page or point it to a specific new location, use such rule (the same as above just specifying exact URL):

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /xxx-index.html http://www.newdomain.com/help/xxx-index.php
```

Apache mod_rewrite manual has a page: [When NOT to use mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect). This particular scenario is listed there (Redirect is much lighter that RewriteRule in terms of resources, which can be an issue on very busy servers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But domain name is same for both urls. And the first url is inside the folder.

Comment: doesn't matter first url is ur older page and second url is new page where you want to redirect.

Comment: If you uploaded .htaccess file to the old-page.html directory and the redirection does not work, it usually means that the .htaccess files are not enabled in the Apache server configuration file httpd.conf.

Comment: Could you please explain ur issue then i will try to help you

Comment: respected sir, I want to redirect a page which mistakenly have an unwanted space in url (`https://website/blog/abc-abc%20abc`) and now I want to redirect it to the right url, which is `https://website/blog/abc-abc-abc`

Comment: go through this url http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect

Comment: This link says to redirect /blog/ folder but I want to redirect a single URL.